# ng test fail after adding 'ng2-dateime '

Tags: angular, ng2-datetime

I have added [ng2-datetime](https://github.com/nkalinov/ng2-datetime) module in my Angular 4 project.

Now problem I am facing with ng test.

Currently it throws error like below.

```
'Cannot find name 'jQuery'
'Cannot find name '$'
```

EDIT:

I did tried same way as most of answer below which is adding below lines in **typings.d.ts**

```
declare var jQuery: any;
declare var $: any;
```

this will start 'ng test' but it will throw error while making build using **ng build --prod**.

```
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'jQuery'
Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '$'
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this on your `typings.d.ts` :

```
declare jQuery: any;
```

The variable will be available in all your app

But if you can, try to avoid plugins that uses `jQuery`

Answer (score 1):

I didn't added **'jQuery'** in 'types' section in **tsconfig.spec.json** file.

After this it started working.

Answer (score 0):

In index.html put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`in a tag and declare this variables in the component.ts where you are using them

```
declare var jquery:any;
declare var $ :any;
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue appens when you use a plugin that requires jQuery without declaring the jQuery variable. You can fix it by adding this on top of your component:

```
declare jQuery: any;
```

However, **using jQuery to accessing your DOM isn't a good practice** in Angular projects, and will be annoying when you'll want to implement things like `angular universal` on your project.

Try with the `ngx-bootstrap` plugin, which contains a cleaner datepicker :

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: Your second error append because it seems you're trying to redeclare a variable that is already declared. Maybe `jQuery` is declared in your component AND in your `typings.d.ts`. Remove the component variable